# Lightmaps in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Lightmaps live independently of other textures, right?

So I have to set up a second set of UVs.

I have exported my JSON object with a second set of UVs and added the following.

```
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = geometry.faceVertexUvs[1];
```

I got no working results. What I'm missing? Maybe someone can wise me a direction. Three.js r.73

```
loader.load("model.js", function(geometry){
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = geometry.faceVertexUvs[1];

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
  color: 0x777777,
  lightMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "lightmap.png" ),
  normalMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "normalmap.png" ),
  specularMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "specularmap.png" )
}));
scene.add(mesh );
});
```

Comment: Try `geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 1 ] = geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lightmaps in three.js require a second set of UVs. One solution is to add a second set of UVs by duplicating the first set.

For `THREE.Geometry` you can do this:

```
geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 1 ] = geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ];
```

For `THREE.BufferGeometry`, use this pattern;

```
var uvs = geometry.attributes.uv.array;
geometry.addAttribute( 'uv2', new THREE.BufferAttribute( uvs, 2 ) );
```

three.js r.73