# how to add the shadow to the model by using lightmap in three,js

Tags: three.js

it is my model: 
[image: model]

it is my the lightmap of this model: 
[image: lightmap]

i have try to use THREE.MeshPhongMaterial like this :

```
var materials=new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    lightMap:lm,
    map: map});
```

but it doesn't work ,there is no shadow appear.
how to add shadow to this model by using the second picture?

Comment: See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054388/lightmaps-in-three-js/34054775#34054775).