# PBR materials reflectivity decreases after lightmaps are being applied in three.js renderer

Tags: three.js, gltf, pbr

I'm a 3d artist working on a 3d architectural configurator based on three.js and Gltf. The configurator uses lightmaps. And I'm experiencing an issue when after lightmaps being applied to the model the PBR materials reflectivity globally decreasing.

Here is a screenshot with a model before applying lightmaps on the left and with lightmaps on the right.

[image: rendering with and without lightmaps]

I wonder if it's possible to have the same reflectivity with lightmaps and without them and where to dig if so.

Thanks!

Comment: Without a live example, one can only guess... Lightmaps require a second set of uv's. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054388/lightmaps-in-three-js/34054775#34054775). Are you applying the lightmap after loading the model?

Comment: The model has the second set of UV's specially prepared for lightmaps. And lightmaps are being applied after loading the model. I'll ask our developer about a live demo possibility.